Origin of "called his name"
Elizabethan English used the expression "call his name":
Translated from Hebrew, Isaiah 9:6:

…
And His name will be called
Wonderful, Counselor, Mighty God,
Everlasting Father, Prince of Peace.

Translated from Greek: Matthew 1:23:

… and they shall call His name Immanuel

Later, Lewis Carroll joked about this expression:
Through the Looking Glass:

“… The name of the song is called 'Haddocks' Eyes'.”
“Oh, that's the name of the song, is it?” Alice said, trying to feel interested.
“No, you don’t understand,” the Knight said, looking a little vexed.
“That’s what the name is called.
The name really is ‘The Aged Aged Man.’”

And today it sounds just as confusing.
Why did they say "call his name" (rather than "called him" or "named him")?

The KJV did not always try to translate into idiomatic English, and preserved many word structures from the original languages. This resulted in many turns of phrase that were not in common use at the time - but which because of the universality and popularity of the KJV became well-known later. So there is a good chance that the origin of "call his name" is actually the KJV.

The use of the possessive pronoun in the third person is a form of respect (Her Majesty,  for instance).

It's from the Hebrew, and the way names are expressed in Hebrew. Isaiah 9:6 is  (biblehub.com):

כִּי־יֶ֣לֶד יֻלַּד־לָ֗נוּ בֵּ֚ן נִתַּן־לָ֔נוּ וַתְּהִ֥י הַמִּשְׂרָ֖ה עַל־שִׁכְמֹ֑ו וַיִּקְרָ֨א שְׁמֹ֜ו פֶּ֠לֶא יֹועֵץ֙ אֵ֣ל גִּבֹּ֔ור אֲבִיעַ֖ד שַׂר־שָׁלֹֽום׃

In part:

וַיִּקְרָ֨א (way-yiq-rā) and will be called
שְׁמ֜וֹ (šə-mōw)  His name
פֶּ֠לֶא (pe-le) Wonderful
יוֹעֵץ֙ (yō-w-‘êṣ) Counselor

(Reading the Hebrew from right to left, of course.)
The KJV (bible.com) translates this as:

For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given: and the government shall be upon his shoulder: and his name shall be called Wonderful, Counsellor, The mighty God, The everlasting Father, The Prince of Peace.

Matthew 1:23 (biblehub.com) copies this form of words in Greek:

καλέσουσιν τὸ ὄνομα αὐτοῦ  Ἐμμανουήλ

Literally:

they will call to the name of Him Emmanouēl (Emmanuel)

And in KJV:

Behold, a virgin shall be with child, and shall bring forth a son, And they shall call his name Emmanuel, which being interpreted is, God with us.

You get similar words in the KJV with Adam (Genesis 5:2) and a lot of other places.
Lewis Carroll is joking on this archaic form of words.

"they will call to the name of Him Emmanouēl"? Where do you get the to from? (Are you translating the Greek definite article τὸ as English preposition to?) KJV parses the accusative expression τὸ ὄνομα αὐτοῦ ("his name," or more literally "the name of him") as direct object of the verb καλέσουσι(ν) ("they will call"), but it can also be parsed as accusative of respect: "As to a name, they will call him Emmanuel."
